# How to use Jest with React Native

Tags: react-native, jestjs

The [testing section](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/testing.html#jest-tests) of the docs for React Native suggest that Jest is the official way to do unit tests. However, they don't explain how to get it setup. Running Jest without any setup gives syntax errors (with no line numbers :( ) because it doesn't apply the transforms (eg ES6 features, JSX and Flow) that React Native code tends to use. There's a `jestSupport` folder in the React Native source try that contains a `env.js` and `scriptPrerocess.js`, the latter has code for apply the transforms. So I've copied those into my project and added the following section to my package.json:

```
  "jest": {
    "scriptPreprocessor": "jestSupport/scriptPreprocess.js",
    "setupEnvScriptFile": "jestSupport/env.js"
  },
```

This fixes the first error but I still get the following error:

```
Using Jest CLI v0.4.0
 FAIL  js/sync/__tests__/SynchronisedStorage-tests.js
SyntaxError: /Users/tom/my-project/js/sync/__tests__/SynchronisedStorage-tests.js: /Users/tom/my-project/js/sync/SynchronisedStorage.js: /Users/tom/my-project/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native.js: /Users/tom/my-project/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/react-tools/src/browser/ui/React.js: /Users/tom/my-project/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/react-tools/src/utils/ReactChildren.js: /Users/tom/my-project/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/react-tools/src/addons/ReactFragment.js: /Users/tom/my-project/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/react-tools/src/classic/element/ReactElement.js: /Users/tom/my-project/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/react-tools/src/core/ReactContext.js: /Users/tom/my-project/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/react-tools/src/vendor/core/warning.js: Unexpected token .
1 test failed, 0 tests passed (1 total)
Run time: 0.456s
```

Is there more I need to do to make Jest understand React Native? Are there any examples of Jest setup to test React Native?

**EDIT:**

There was a check in `scriptPreprocess` that stopped it from running over any file in `node_modules` which of course included the whole of React Native. Removing that fixes the error above. However, I'm now getting more errors from the React Native source, it definitely seems like it isn't meant to be run within Jest.

**EDIT2:**

Explicitly setting the mock for the `react-native` module works:

```
jest.setMock('react-native', {});
```

That seems like it's going to be very manual and not very useful for testing code that interacts with the React Native API a lot. I definitely still feel like I'm missing something!

Comment: Where is this `jestSupport` directory of which you speak? I'm not seeing it in a React-native 0.4 or 0.7 project.

Comment: It's not included in the NPM package but you can get it from Github: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/jestSupport

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got Jest to work for my React Native application, and it is running tests without any problem on files with ES6 and ES7 transforms.

To get Jest to work, I followed these steps:

1. Copied the [`jestSupport`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/jestSupport) folder from the React Native master repo to my `react-native` folder in `node_modules`.
2. Edited the "jest" line in my `packages.json` to points to the files in the `jestSupport` folder

The "jest" line in my `packages.json` now looks lke this:

```
"jest": {
  "scriptPreprocessor": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jestSupport/scriptPreprocess.js",
  "setupEnvScriptFile": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jestSupport/env.js",
  "testFileExtensions": [
    "js"
  ],
  "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
    "source-map"
  ]
},
```

Comment: Looks like jestSupport folder is already in react-native, so no need to copy it there. At least since version 0.13

Comment: Could you kindly create a sample working repo? I'm getting `ReferenceError: _reactNative is not defined` error.

Comment: I'm getting `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/node_modules/react-native/jestSupport/env.js'`

Answer (score 5):

As of React Native v0.37.0, Jest is part of the new app template.

In a new app you can run tests right away:

```
$ react-native init MyAwesomeApp
$ cd MyAwesomeApp
$ npm test
...
Tests:       2 passed
```

Answer (score 2):

For newer versions of [jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-cli), setting it up for `react-native` is very easy.

Install jest using

```
npm install --save-dev jest-cli babel-jest
```

In `package.json`, add this

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "babel-node ./server/server.js",
  "import-data": "babel-node ./scripts/import-data-from-parse.js",
  "update-schema": "babel-node ./server/schema/updateSchema.js",
  "test": "jest",
  "lint": "eslint ."
},
"jest": {
  "haste": {
    "defaultPlatform": "ios",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "providesModuleNodeModules": [
      "react-native"
    ]
  }
},
```

You might only need to add lines related to jest

Now you can use

```
npm test
```

to run jest.

Refer to [f8app](https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app)'s github repo to find more about this.

Comment: JSX doesn't seem to work in jest test files when following these instructions

Comment: Fails for me too. I was getting error about no scriptPreprocessor so I added ```    "scriptPreprocessor": "node_modules/react-native/jestSupport/preprocessor.js",
    "setupEnvScriptFile": "node_modules/react-native/jestSupport/env.js",  ``` to `package.json` under `jest` section. 

Now I get `Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "/Users/carlf/Documents/dev/react-native/AwesomeProject"` 

Do I need to `npm install babel-jest`? Doesn't 'jestSupport/preprocessor.js' take care of babel?

btw: The F8 app doesn't actually have any test scripts.

Comment: As we all know, Jest claims it's a `Zero configuration testing platform`. This thread suggests otherwise. I'm new to Jest. If I want to use it, do I need to learn how to configure this zero-config platform? Have the issues in this thread been resolved in the last 2 years?