# How to test React Native components

Tags: unit-testing, react-native

I'm trying to figure out how to test React Native (not React JS) components. Even looking at React Native's starter code, its difficult to see how to test it.

```
var AwesomeProject = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.ios.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
          Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

I've been able to use Babel to transpile the JSX syntax as well as use Mockery to mock the React library methods `createClass` and `StyleSheet.create`, but at the end of the day, I can't seem to create any meaningful tests.

Comment: I think we want something similar to Reacts Shallow Rendering testing technique which is used for React web.  I've posted this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804218/in-react-native-how-can-i-test-my-components-with-shallow-rendering

Comment: See this Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29730415/how-to-use-jest-with-react-native#comment50964358_29730415

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I setup a repo with TravisCI using Mocha for BDD style unit tests. You can see the repo at: https://github.com/sghiassy/react-native-sglistview

Answer (score 3):

You should mock up React Native package as well as set babel transformer and some other settings. Maybe you could check unit tests for my component, React Native Router Flux:

[https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/tree/master/**tests**](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/tree/master/__tests__)

Answer (score 3):

To run tests with Jest you should replace ReactNative with React using `__mocks__` folder, use `TestUtils` with shallow renderer and maybe [react-shallow-renderer-helpers](https://github.com/robrichard/react-shallow-renderer-helpers) to lookup virtual tree.

I've made sample repository with unit tests [here](https://github.com/ertrzyiks/react-native-component-test) and article about my way through it [here](http://www.schibsted.pl/2015/10/testing-react-native-components-with-jest/)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at ReactNative's UIExplorer example project, which is set up with several hybrid XCTest & require('NativeModules').TestModule test suites.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/UIExplorer/UIExplorerIntegrationTests/js

Comment: Those tests don't seem to be written in Javascript.  I think we are looking for JS unit tests.

Comment: I changed the URL to take you directly to the ES6 files.

Comment: that link 404's now