# In React Native how can I test my components with Shallow Rendering?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

For [React](http://facebook.github.io/react/), I use [Shallow Rendering](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html#shallow-rendering) techniques for unit testing my React components.  Can I do something similar in [React Native](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/)?

I've [followed the instructions to set up Jest](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/testing.html#jest-tests), but can't find any documentation on testing my components.  I would like to do full TDD with React Native in the same way I do with React.

Comment: Good question. The official docs are extremely brief to say the least..

Comment: https://medium.com/@jcfrancisco/unit-testing-react-native-components-a-firsthand-guide-cea561df242b#.qeg60edil

Comment: As far as I'm aware react-native doesn't really make too many assumptions about iOS or Android environments. Can't you just use Jest and pretend like it's a web app? Won't all the dependencies be mocked?

Comment: I tried using Jest but found it to be too slow.  Even with Jest in place, what I'm interested is the way that React uses Shallow Rendering to allow us to test shallow representations of the components.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think [enzyme](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/) is what you're looking for.

It provides you a `shallow` function which allows you to make a shallow comparison (as you want).

Enzyme can be used along with all of the popular test runners (like Mocha, Jest, Karma etc). Full list can be found [on the library's github page](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme).

Example:

```js
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';

describe('<MyComponent />', () => {
  it('should render three <Foo /> components', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
    expect(wrapper.find(Foo)).to.have.length(3);
  });
});
```

For the further reading you can take a look on enzyme's [Shallow Rendering API](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/shallow.md) or [docs](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/tree/master/docs) in general.

Comment: Hmm.  Enzyme seems to have a dependency on react-dom.  Isn't that going to conflict with react-native in some way?

Comment: don't find by a component name, instead find by a test attribute so that you don't couple your tests to the component name.  If you rename the component you don't want your tests to break, it's still the same component under test

Comment: react-dom is needed for jsdom and you only need jsdom if using enzyme mount, so no it won't conflict with react-native, only enzyme will be using that

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without using `enzyme`, just use [Shallow Renderer](https://reactjs.org/docs/shallow-renderer.html) from `react-test-renderer`.

```
import ShallowRenderer from 'react-test-renderer/shallow';

it('renders', () => {
  const renderer = new ShallowRenderer();
  const wrapper = renderer.render(<MyComponent />);

  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Comment: what is wrapper in this line "expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();"

Comment: I have updated the answer, thanks for asking. I hope it is correct now