# Runtime error Running Jest : in React

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

I'm unable to run Jest tests and have a very vague error message.
I found a similar issue on StackOverflow, and I wasn't able to solve it with their suggestion of adding jestSupport in the react folder in the node_module.

issue referenced: 
[How to use Jest with React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29730415/how-to-use-jest-with-react-native)

```
    __tests__/profile-test.js
● Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'DEFINE_MANY' of undefined
```

// Snippet from package.JSON

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "scriptPreprocessor": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest"
  },
```

// test file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import Profile from '../components/profile';
jest.setMock('react', {}); // put this in after reading a troubleshooting article

//jest.autoMockOff(Profile);


       describe('Profile'), () => {

        it("renders a form containing user information", function() {
            let Profile = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Profile/>);
            let renderedDOM = () => React.findDOMNode(Profile);

            expect(renderedDOM.tagName).toBe('div');
            expect(renderedDOM.classList).toEqual(['value', 'image', 'btn btn-primary', 'btn btn-danger' ]);

           var children = renderedDOM.querySelectorAll('fieldConfig.type'); //created a custom
            expect(children.length).toBe(3);
            expect(children[0]).toEqual({name: 'test mc nameyname', email: 'testmcnameyname@gmail.com'}); 
          });
        };
```

Has anyone run into this issue before, & have suggestions?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't. I decided to pivot to Mocha, Chai and Enzyme explicitly for clarity of error messages after speaking with a colleague.

Answer (score 9):

Putting this in my `package.json` at the same level as "scripts" worked for me:

```
"jest": {
  "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
    "react"
  ]
}
```

I did not have any jest.dontMock statements at the top of my test file. I used jest.unmock for the module under test only.

Comment: This solved the problem for me too, but no clue why.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, you're requiring the mocked versions of all the modules.

Try putting

```
jest.dontMock('react')
jest.dontMock('react-dom')
jest.dontMock('react-addons-test-utils')
jest.dontMock('../components/profile')
```

at the top of the file.

I would also get rid of:

```
jest.setMock('react', {});
```

Try all of that and as far I can tell it should work.