# How to use enzyme for react-native with jest

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I have followed –or tried to– several posts on how to do it, including the airbnb enzyme's guide for (separatedly) `react-native` and `jest`. (E.g: https://medium.com/@childsmaidment/testing-react-native-components-with-enzyme-d46bf735540#.6sxq10kgt, https://blog.callstack.io/unit-testing-react-native-with-the-new-jest-i-snapshots-come-into-play-68ba19b1b9fe#.4iqylmqh5 or [How to use Jest with React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29730415/how-to-use-jest-with-react-native))

But I keep getting lots of warnings (I have multiple set of concurrent tests) whenever I try to render (not mount, it crashes) any native component. Warnings are always about a native prop not being recognised.

```
Warning: Unknown props `focus`, `secureTextEntry` on <TextInput> tag. Remove these props from the element.
          in TextInput (created by TextInput)
          in TextInput (created by PasswordInput)
```

Anyone who has a set up working, recognises how to remove the warning or how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you rendering <TextInput> in your own components ? Looks like you're passing some unrecognize props.
Can you add your component's implementation as well as the test ?
I could use a bit more context in order to help you ;)

Answer (score 5):

So I know this is a bit old but I was having issues with Jest, Enzyme, and React Native and I found this post - hopefully this solution will help.

To start with - Enzyme doesn't support mounting React Native and only supports shallow rendering. This wasn't good enough for me as I needed end-to-end tests from the component to the api which lead me to [react-native-mock-render](https://github.com/Root-App/react-native-mock-render). What this does is allow us to run react native inside a browser environment which let's us test using Enzyme - all the calls for React Native and the components work as you would expect.

To set this up you'll need to install [JSDOM](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/guides/jsdom.html), react-native-mock-render, Enzyme 3.0+, and Jest 20.0.0+. And then inside your jest setup file (which is specified in your package.json) include the following code:

```
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');

const jsdom = new JSDOM();
const { window } = jsdom;

function copyProps(src, target) {
  const props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(src)
    .filter(prop => typeof target[prop] === 'undefined')
    .map(prop => Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(src, prop));
  Object.defineProperties(target, props);
}

global.window = window;
global.document = window.document;
global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node.js',
};
copyProps(window, global);

// Setup adapter to work with enzyme 3.2.0
const Enzyme = require('enzyme');
const Adapter = require('enzyme-adapter-react-16');

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

// Ignore React Web errors when using React Native
console.error = (message) => {
  return message;
};

require('react-native-mock-render/mock');
```

And that's it - you're all setup to mount components in Enzyme and test them.

If you want to see a full sample check out [react-native-mock-render-example](https://github.com/herman-rogers/react-native-mock-render-example). This is working with React 16, React Native 0.51, and Enzyme 3.2.

Comment: Hi I tried your solution but I get the error `node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js: missing super() call in constructor`.

Do you know a way around this? I've heard others say it's a problem with babel. I'm using babel-preset-react-native `v4.0.0`.

Cheers!

Comment: Well I'm assuming this has to do with super() not being called in some constructor inside jsdom. Can you list what version of jsdom you're using? For my .babelrc all I have is ```{ presets: [ "react-native" ]}```

Comment: @Antonio did you find a solution for your issue? I have the same error.

Answer (score 1):

In order to unit test your component with jest you can use enzyme-to-json

```
npm install --save enzyme-to-json
```

then your test would look like this:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { shallowToJson } from 'enzyme-to-json';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

it('should render component', => {
  expect(shallowToJson(shallow(<MyComponent />))).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Comment: I do this already, but i am more interested in navigating through component props.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure regarding your case with react-native.
I can share my case of using jest + enzyme with standard react.

When I needed to test some component and isolate it from others I used `jest.mock`, e.g.

```
jest.mock('../ComponentToBeMocked', () => {
  return () => null;
});
```

Initially I found examples when the second argument (a function) should return just a string representing a name of the mocked component. But in that case I saw that distracting `Unknown props` warning.

Comment: The problem with react-native is that the DOM is not compatible.